# Ansible - Check if Drive is Mounted

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create an EBS role for my Ansible scripts. I'm going to be creating the EBS volume and attaching it myself for now through the console. I want this role to run commands and mount the drive if the drive isn't already mounted, but skip this if it's already mounted.

I have host specific vars that give a list of disks and mount points:

```
ebs_vols:
  - drive: /dev/sdb
    mount_point: /mnt/ebs1
    directory: /var/lib/mysql
  - drive: /dev/sdc
    mount_point: /mnt/ebs2
    directory: /var/backups
```

I want to have my task check each drive with a `df` command and see if it's mounted. Then skip commands if the drive is mounted:

```
- name: Check if drives are already mounted
  shell: df | grep "{{item.drive}}" | wc -l
  with_items: "{{ebs_vols}}"
  register: ebs_checked

- name: output debug
  debug: var=ebs_checked

- name: Make filesystem
  filesystem:
    fstype: xfs
    dev: "{{item.item.drive}}"
  when: "{{item.stdout}} == 0"
  with_items: ebs_checked.results
```

When I run it, it seems to check each disk just fine because the output of the `debug` is an object with the correct drives and stdout. The problem is with the `Make filesystem` task. The errors out with the following error:

> The conditional check '{{item.stdout}} == 0' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ({{item.stdout}} == 0): 'ansible.vars.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\n

What am I missing here and what is the best way to skip commands if the drive is already mounted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use "bare variables" anymore in Ansible. The following line causes Ansible to interpret the `ebs_checked.results` value as a string:

```
with_items: ebs_checked.results
```

Use the correct syntax instead:

```
with_items: "{{ ebs_checked.results }}"
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Rookie mistake. I'm new to Ansible and I guess I was expecting some kind of Syntax error instead of it trying actually execute it. Thanks!

Comment: There is no syntax error. `item` is assigned a string value of `ebs_checked.results` and you got an error that it doesn't contain the `stdout` key you tried to use.

Comment: This use of bare variables in `with_` loops was deprecated in Ansible 2.0, and removed in 2.2 - see the [Ansible 2.0 porting guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/porting_guide_2.0.html#deprecated).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try:

```
- name: Check if drives are already mounted
  command: '/bin/mountpoint -q {{item.directory}}'
  with_items: '{{ebs_vols}}'
  register: ebs_checked
  changed_when: "ebs_checked.rc != 0"
```

Also, ansible's setup module does populate an `ansible_mounts` array, but I haven't had a chance to see if it would be helpful in this context.